# Delete first part of line

Tags: bash, sed

Given the following file

```
$ cat a.txt
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I can easily remove the first part using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.*fox//' a.txt
 jumps over the lazy dog
```

I tried to be clever with the `D` option

```
D      Delete  up  to  the first embedded newline in the pattern space.
```

example

```
$ sed 's/fox/\n/; D' a.txt
```

However this gives no output. Can the first part of a line be removed with `sed` using the `D` option similar to what I have tried?

This works if the part before `fox` is shorter than the part after.

```
$ sed 's/fox/\r/' a.txt
 jumps over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 's/fox/\n/;T;D' file
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to to it:

```
sed '/fox/{s/fox/\n/;D}' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete help text:

> Delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline.  If any text
>   is left, restart cycle with the resultant pattern space (without
>   reading a new line of input), otherwise start a normal new cycle.

Your example doesn't work because `D` will restart the cycle and keep deleting lines until nothing is left.

If you really want to use `D`, *perreal's* answer would do, or perhaps you would prefer to use conditional branching (`t` or GNU only `T`). Here's a GNU and BSD compatible version:

*parse.sed*

```
s/fox/\
/
t del
b
:del
D
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -f parse.sed a.txt
```

Output:

```
 jumps over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if the part before `fox` is shorter than the part after.

```sh
$ sed 's/fox/\r/' a.txt
 jumps over the lazy dog
```